# do I have to respect order of commands in pyspark sql?

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql

I am learning pyspark sql and, I am unsure if the order for the function has to be the next? groupby() agg() join() select()

```py
test = test.groupBy('year')\
           .agg(f.max('value').alias('value'))\
           .join(sch,['year','value'])\
           .select(['year','station','value'])
```

I am used to pure sql where the ordering is select from where, etc...Here, I tried putting the groupBy() at the end but it fails... so I assume there must be an ordering to be respected. Where is this order specified?

I checked https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html but it does not say anything about respecting the order of the commands.

Answer (score 0):

The code which you wrote is in pyspark dataframe. you can write same code using pyspark sql.

spark.sql("select year,station,max(value) as value from test join sch on  group by year")

pyspark sql is similar to mysql.

the order of execution is 
**join** the datasets, 
check **where** condition,
**groupby**,
**select** and **order** the data

you can learn pyspark from following link: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLf0swTFhTI8rT3ApjBqt338MCO0ZvReFt